# Websockets error Connection closed on subdomain with Chrome

Tags: javascript, http, google-chrome, websocket

I'm on a domain www.example.com and am trying to make a websocket upgrade request to api.example.com. When I do this I get an error 
`failed: Connection closed before receiving a handshake response`. I don't even see the request make it to the server.

However if I type api.example.com in my browser, the server send a redirect to www.example.com and the client will end up on the same page however the request will go through to the server and upgrade will work.

I thought this could be something with CORS but it is a get request so it should atleast make it to the server. I also do not see a preflight request.

Any ideas why this could be happening?

Edit: It works on Firefox, but does not work on Chrome.

Comment: maybe the browser did preflight request before and cached it? I have seen this happening before.

Comment: I do not see a preflight request on the server. Would it be something other than an options request?

Comment: One possible trap is: if the JavaScript comes from a HTML page over HTTP**S**, then the WebSocket connection MUST be secure ("wss"). The target hostname/domain/subdomain *can* differ, but it must be secure WebSocket.

Comment: Is the certificate sent for WSS completely valid (acceptable to the browser without user interaction)? E.g. is it issued for your subdomain (or a wildcard cert)?

Comment: It's a cert issued for all matching subdomains. (The cert matches *.example.com.)